# Kubernetes logging with fluentd daemonset

Tags: logging, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, fluentd

I have my fluentd-daemonset configured in kubernetes cluster to send logs to cloudwatch. I followed [this](https://eksworkshop.com/logging/deploy/) tutorial and set fluentd. However in cloudwatch I can see that I see the logs by fluentd as well. How can I stop fluentd logs to be pushed to cloudwatch?

This is the config file I use,

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_container_logs
  @label @containers
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag *
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </parse>
</source>

<label @containers>
  <filter **>
    @type kubernetes_metadata
    @id filter_kube_metadata
  </filter>

  <filter **>
    @type record_transformer
    @id filter_containers_stream_transformer
    <record>
      stream_name ${tag_parts[3]}
    </record>
  </filter>

  <match **>
    @type cloudwatch_logs
    @id out_cloudwatch_logs_containers
    region "#{ENV.fetch('REGION')}"
    log_group_name "/eks/#{ENV.fetch('CLUSTER_NAME')}/containers"
    log_stream_name_key stream_name
    remove_log_stream_name_key true
    auto_create_stream true
    retention_in_days "#{ENV.fetch('RETENTION_IN_DAYS')}"
    <buffer>
      flush_interval 5
      chunk_limit_size 2m
      queued_chunks_limit_size 32
      retry_forever true
    </buffer>
  </match>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I excluded fluentd logs with `exclude_path` in the configuration as follows and now I don't get them.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_container_logs
  @label @containers
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  exclude_path ["/var/log/containers/*fluentd*"]
  tag *
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </parse>
</source>
```

Answer (score 1):

`fluent.**` has been deprecated, we could use this match annotation in order to exclude fluentd logs:

```xml
    <match @FLUENT_LOG>
      @type null
    </match>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work as per annotation:

```
<match fluent.**>
  @type null
</match>
```

For example for this settings:

```
<match fluent.**>
  @type file
  path /var/log/internal/my-fluentd.log
  compress gzip
</match>
```

As per documentation, you can exclude those logs using this configuration:

```
exclude_path ["/var/log/internal/*.gz"]
```